# Why getVoiceInteractor () returns null?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get VoiceInteractor, but the getVoiceInteractor() method always returns null. In the manifest, I wrote the following:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity_2">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Activity_1:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      startActivity(new Intent(Activity_1.this, Activity_2.class));
}
```

Activity_2:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       VoiceInteractor mInteractor;
       mInteractor = getVoiceInteractor();
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the code where you call `getVoiceInteractor()` and what you are doing before calling it

Comment: @JensV, Updated the question, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation seems a bit unclear, but I found the following clues:

- [`startLocalVoiceInteraction()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startLocalVoiceInteraction(android.os.Bundle)) seems to be needed to be able to get the `VoiceInteractor`
- [`onLocalVoiceInteractionStarted()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onLocalVoiceInteractionStarted()) seems to indicate when you can call `getVoiceInteractor`
- The last clue came from `onGetDirectAction` where it states:

  > To get the voice interactor you need to call getVoiceInteractor() which would **return non null only if there is an ongoing voice interaction session**

This means your code should look something like this:

```java
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    startLocalVoiceInteraction(new Bundle());
  }

  @Override
  public void onLocalVoiceInteractionStarted() {
    getVoiceInteractor(); // Should be non-null here
  }
}
```

Comment: You're a genius.Thanks!!! Tell me more, please, how to close the voice assistant programmatically called by the VoiceInteractor.CompleteVoiceRequest method?

Comment: @МаксимПетров I assume [`stopLocalVoiceInteraction`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#stopLocalVoiceInteraction()) should terminate it again.

Comment: Thank you very much, you made my day!

Comment: Please tell me if you happen to know how to get getVoiceInteractor() when the app is minimized?

Comment: Also on the locked screen and minimized app?